# UISearch bar changes results after searching

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisearchbar

i am implementing search bar in a tableview but after search my address is changed from actual address, what should i do now

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{

    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        filteredListResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        GWTG *gwtg ;
        for (gwtg in listResults)
        {
            NSRange nameRange = [gwtg.celebrity_name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];//NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
            NSRange descriptionRange = [gwtg.location_name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [filteredListResults addObject:gwtg];
            }
        }
    }

    [tblSearch reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What do you meant by this "after search my address is changed from actual address"? Could you pls elaborate.

Comment: i have an array of address,i solved my problem , thanks i was using previous array after searching :)